# static electricity binds pages during printing

Tags: laser-printer, static-discharge

I have a Dell 1135n desktop printer.  It has the option of 2-sided printing.  This feature requires that I print one side and then manually turn the pages over to print the other.

Unfortunately, in the process of printing the first side so much static electricity builds up that the pages cling to each other.  Then after I flip the pages and try to print the second side invariably a paper jam results.  I almost always end up having to start a new print job using one-sided printing, even if I let the pages sit for 10 minutes or maybe longer to cool off and then 'shuffle' or 'fluff' them before trying to print the second side.

Today I even experienced pages clinging to each other when using one-sided printing.

I do not know the culprit.  Maybe it is the printer, maybe it is the paper, maybe it is the climate (I am in Alaska), maybe it is me.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reduce static electricity and improve performance when using a computer desktop printer?  As it is, this two-sided printing feature ends up wasting far more paper than it saves.

Comment: I used to work at staples and I would hear of that problem a lot. The usual trick is to break the pages apart before opening the reem/package. To do this, take the unopened reem and hit it against a table or desk, then use the printer as per normal.

If the problem is static, this won't fix it - but its  worth a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Logan Bissonnette  notes this can be addressed by breaking the static bond between sheets.  I "fan" the stack of paper before inserting in the tray. Hold one end and fan the stack a few times.  This was suggested by HP and Epson support.

Likley low humidity does not help so adding some mosture to the room can help.

Comment: Also, try blowing between the pages while you fan them. Moisture from your breath is more effective than room moisture.

Answer (score 2):

Try grounding the paper stack by laying it on top of a heavy metal desk. Also, ground yourself before loading the paper in the printer. If the printer is in a carpeted room, that might be causing the trouble. I know at a computer lab I once used in the winter the printer would jam almost every job on account of the static developed.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try your suggestion.  I could have given the check mark to any of the three answers.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with static, many more expensive printers have an ionizer that "sprays" the paper to encourage it to discharge.  But this feature may not be present in less-expensive printers.

In that case, the best solution is to humidify the air.  A small room humidifier, placed near the printer, should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same problem, but I fixed it by using my printer's "paper flap" as seen  [here](http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/28-112-191-Z01?$S300W$) but not [here](http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/28-112-191-Z02?$S300W$). It seems to keep the paper from rubbing against other sheets and the printer itself as each page is printed.

[image: SU531724 example]